# Creating image hover effect where the text isn't affected by the opacity

Tags: html, css, image, hover, opacity

I'm trying to create an image hover effect, but I'm having 1 of two 2 issues:

1. The text AND the background are opaque (I only want the background to be opaque. I want the text to stay normal.)
2. The image will hover and transition correctly, but then if I hover over the text, the whole image goes back to the original version of the image.

I've tried several different methods, but I can't get past both of those issues at the same time. So what I want to accomplish is:

-Start with an opaque image and normal color text, and then upon hover, the image goes normal and the text stays the same, and all of the image stays normal while the cursor is over the image.

Here's my code:

```css
.outer {
   opacity: 0.25;
      -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
        -o-transition: all .5s ease;
       -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
         transition: all .5s ease;
    }
    .outer:hover{
      opacity: 1.0;
   cursor: pointer;
    }

    h2.image-headings {
   position: absolute;
   top: 40%;
   width: 100%;
   font-size: 60px;
   color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <img src="http://wasatchhospitality.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/wasatch-elements.jpg">
    <h2 class="image-headings">Management Team</h2>
    </div>
```

This code shows the text and image starting off opaque. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to change the opacity of the image, change your rules to change/transition opacity on the image - not the parent div.

```css
.outer img {
  opacity: 0.25;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.outer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.outer:hover img {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

h2.image-headings {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <img src="http://wasatchhospitality.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/wasatch-elements.jpg">
  <h2 class="image-headings">Management Team</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. I thought I had tried something similar but I must have been missing something.

Comment: @CTUSS38 awesome, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a JQuery plugin to do this because they are pretty good animated and its easy to